# How do I get from C# thread to the object which member function was the parameter to that thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

In C# threads are created by passing a member function:

```
class SomeClass {
   public void ThreadFunction() {Thread.Sleep( Infinite ); }
};


SomeClass myObject = new SomeClass();
Thread thread = new Thread( myObject.ThreadFunction );
thread.Start();
```

Here `ThreadFunction()` is not static, so I guess the object reference is passed to `Thread` constructor.

How can code inside `ThreadFunction()` get to `myObject`? Do I just use `this` reference for that?

Comment: Yep, this is perfectly ok. I.e. you can use any fields, properties or methods from ThreadFunction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
class SomeClass {
  public void ThreadFunction(Object obj) 
  {
    SomeClass myObject = (SomeClass)obj;
    Thread.Sleep( Infinite ); 
  }
};


SomeClass myObject = new SomeClass();
Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(myObject.ThreadFunction) );
thread.Start(myObject)
```

Comment: It seems like overkill for this. It useful if we could call ThreadFunction for another object. But this situation seems very weird to me.

Answer (score 4):

In the exact example you give, simply by accessing `this`.

In the general case, you can also do something like

```
class SomeClass {
   public void ThreadFunction(object param)
   {
     var justAnExample = (string)param;
   }
};


SomeClass myObject = new SomeClass();
Thread thread = new Thread(myObject.ThreadFunction);
thread.Start("parameter");
```

This allows you to pass a parameter of any type (here, a `string`) to the thread function. If you need more than one, then you can always pass in a `Tuple` or an `object[]` or any other container of values.

If you go this way, you might want to make `ThreadFunction` `static` (this will lose you the option of using `this`) as well.